# Can not read avro in DataProc Spark with spark-avro

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-avro

I have a cluster on Google DataProc (with image 1.4) and I want to read avro files with Spark from google cloud storage. I follow this guide: [Spark read avro](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html).

The command I ran is:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark test.py \
--cluster $CLUSTER_NAME \
--region $REGION \
--properties spark.jars.packages='org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.1'
```

test.py is very simple, just

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("avro").load("gs://mybucket/abc.avro")

df.show()
```

I got the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o196.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.<init>(AvroFileFormat.scala:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 24 more
```

Even if I ssh to master node and start the shell there with `spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.1`, running `val usersDF = spark.read.format("avro").load("gs://mybucket/abc.avro")` has the same error.

Why this happens? Thank you.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError usually occurs if there are version mismatch, as it is calling a method but that is no longer available, check spark 2.4 compatible spark-avro, may be try with org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.0

Comment: I was aware that version mismatch can be the issue, but I've tested several versions including 2.4.0 and the databricks one, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dataproc 1.4 uses Spark 2.4.0](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-1.4), not Spark 2.4.1, which normally wouldn't be expected to be a problem, but whereas [Spark 2.4.0 uses Scala 2.11](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/#downloading), [Spark 2.4.1 uses Scala 2.12](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/#downloading).

You can also see the avro artifact on a Dataproc cluster under `/usr/lib/spark/external`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/spark/external
total 13656
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   187385 Mar  6 23:25 spark-avro_2.11-2.4.0.jar
...
```

So you just need to use:

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0
```